# How can I capture window focus change event with c#

Tags: c#, events, window, focus

I want to build an application to monitor all running windows focus change event. I know WM_KILLFOCUS (0x0008) and WM_SETFOCUS(0x0007) and when window lost focus or get focus, the message will be sent. with help of spy++, I get output like this:

<00001> 0005069A S WM_SETFOCUS hwndLoseFocus:(null)

<00002> 0005069A R WM_SETFOCUS

<00003> 0005069A S WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:(null)

<00004> 0005069A R WM_KILLFOCUS

<00005> 00010096 S WM_SETFOCUS hwndLoseFocus:(null)

<00006> 00010096 R WM_SETFOCUS

I tried to write following c# code to make it work in my winfrom application:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NativeMessage
{
 public IntPtr handle;
 public uint msg;
 public IntPtr wParam;
 public IntPtr lParam;
 public uint time;
 public System.Drawing.Point p;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern sbyte GetMessage(out NativeMessage lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);

NativeMessage msg = new NativeMessage();
        sbyte ret;
        while ((ret = GetMessage( out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0)) != -1)
        {
            if (ret == -1)
            {
                //-1 indicates an error
            }
            else
            {
                if (msg.msg == 0x0008 || msg.msg == 0x0007)
                {
                    this.textBox1.Text = "ret is: " + ret;
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, I never get message WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS.

I actually want to trigger an event in my application when I find the get/lost focus event happens in all running windows. How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Form.LostFocus` and `Form.GotFocus` events? These events are basically triggered by `WM_KILLFOCUS`  and `WM_SETFOCUS` its the windows forms representation of these messages.

Comment: I think he wants to monitor focus on all windows(applications) running, not only on his application, so he can't just subscribe to events that easily. That's the only scenario I would need/choose to monitor win messages, anyway.

Comment: Loana, you are correct. I want to build out an application to monitor all windows running. In my application, I want: a: monitor all windows get/lost focus, b: when get/lost focus event happen in all windows, trigger an event in my application.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Form.Actived` and `Form.Deactivate` events to find out whether the form lost or got the focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get into the nasty world of native window messages you should use [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc.aspx)